# MemoryStream: Encoding

Tags: .net, encoding

I'm trying to encrypt a very long text using public and private keys of a X509 certificate. Specifically, I'm trying to reproduce this MSDN code: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.publickey(v=vs.90).aspx

However, instead of encrypting a file, I want to encrypt a string. So I'm trying to adapt the code to use MemoryStreams.

The problem is that every time I try to read the content of the stream, it has strange caracters. So when i try to call a webservice (asmx) and sending it the cipher text, it crashes.

This is my code. I have tried using UTF32, UTF8, UTF7 and ASCII.

```
Private Shared Function encryptText(ByVal token As String, ByVal rsaPublicKey As Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider) As String
    Dim aesManaged As New Security.Cryptography.AesManaged()
    Dim transform As Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform = Nothing
    Dim outStreamEncrypted As Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream = Nothing
    Dim outFsaux As New IO.MemoryStream()
    Dim outFs As New IO.StreamWriter(outFsaux, Text.Encoding.ASCII)
    Dim inFs As New IO.MemoryStream(Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(token))
    Dim cipherText As String = String.Empty


    Try
        aesManaged.KeySize = 256
        aesManaged.BlockSize = 128
        aesManaged.Mode = Security.Cryptography.CipherMode.CBC

        Dim keyFormatter As New Security.Cryptography.RSAPKCS1KeyExchangeFormatter(rsaPublicKey)
        Dim keyEncrypted As Byte() = keyFormatter.CreateKeyExchange(aesManaged.Key, aesManaged.GetType())

        Dim LenK(3) As Byte
        Dim LenIV(3) As Byte

        Dim lKey As Integer = keyEncrypted.Length
        LenK = BitConverter.GetBytes(lKey)
        Dim lIV As Integer = aesManaged.IV.Length
        LenIV = BitConverter.GetBytes(lIV)

        outFs.Write(LenK)
        outFs.Write(LenIV)
        outFs.Write(keyEncrypted)
        outFs.Write(aesManaged.IV)

        transform = aesManaged.CreateEncryptor()

        outStreamEncrypted = New Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream(outFs.BaseStream, transform, Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write)
        Dim count As Integer = 0
        Dim offset As Integer = 0

        Dim blockSizeBytes As Integer = aesManaged.BlockSize / 8
        Dim data(blockSizeBytes) As Byte
        Dim bytesRead As Integer = 0

        Do
            count = inFs.Read(data, 0, blockSizeBytes)
            offset += count
            outStreamEncrypted.Write(data, 0, count)
            bytesRead += blockSizeBytes
        Loop While count > 0

        inFs.Flush()
        outStreamEncrypted.FlushFinalBlock()

        outFsaux.Position = 0
        cipherText = System.Convert.ToBase64String(outFsaux.ToArray())
    Finally
        If inFs IsNot Nothing Then inFs.Dispose()
        If outFs IsNot Nothing Then outFs.Dispose()
        If outStreamEncrypted IsNot Nothing Then outStreamEncrypted.Dispose()
        If transform IsNot Nothing Then transform.Dispose()
    End Try

    Return cipherText
End Function
```

UPGRADE:

Thanks for the help. I have updated the above code too.

Now I can correctly encrypt text. However, I still need help, for adapt the decrypt method. It crashes when it tries to create the variable KeyDecrypted

I know that the problem is that, on encrypt method, it loads some info at the begining of the cipher string, which decrypt method cannot recover properly after the Base64 conversion.

```
  Private Shared Function decryptText(ByVal token As String, ByVal rsaPrivateKey As Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider) As String
    Dim aesManaged As New Security.Cryptography.AesManaged()
    Dim inFs As IO.MemoryStream = New IO.MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(token))
    Dim outFs As New IO.MemoryStream
    Dim outStreamDecrypted As Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream = Nothing

    Dim decipherText As String = String.Empty

    aesManaged.KeySize = 256
    aesManaged.BlockSize = 128
    aesManaged.Mode = Security.Cryptography.CipherMode.CBC

    Dim LenK() As Byte = New Byte(4 - 1) {}
    Dim LenIV() As Byte = New Byte(4 - 1) {}


    inFs.Seek(0, IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)
    inFs.Seek(0, IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)
    inFs.Read(LenK, 0, 3)
    inFs.Seek(4, IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)
    inFs.Read(LenIV, 0, 3)

    Dim lengthK As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(LenK, 0)
    Dim lengthIV As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(LenIV, 0)

    Dim startC As Integer = lengthK + lengthIV + 8
    Dim lenC As Integer = (CType(inFs.Length, Integer) - startC)

    Dim KeyEncrypted() As Byte = New Byte(lengthK - 1) {}
    Dim IV() As Byte = New Byte(lengthIV - 1) {}

    inFs.Seek(8, IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)
    inFs.Read(KeyEncrypted, 0, lengthK)
    inFs.Seek(8 + lengthK, IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)
    inFs.Read(IV, 0, lengthIV)

    Dim KeyDecrypted As Byte() = rsaPrivateKey.Decrypt(KeyEncrypted, False)
    Dim transform As Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform = aesManaged.CreateDecryptor(KeyDecrypted, IV)


    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Dim offset As Integer = 0

    Dim blockSizeBytes As Integer = aesManaged.BlockSize / 8
    Dim data(blockSizeBytes) As Byte

    inFs.Seek(startC, IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)

    outStreamDecrypted = New Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream(outFs, transform, Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write)
    Do
        count = inFs.Read(data, 0, blockSizeBytes)
        offset += count
        outStreamDecrypted.Write(data, 0, count)
    Loop While count > 0

    outFs.Position = 0
    Using rd As New IO.StreamReader(outFs)
        decipherText = rd.ReadToEnd()
    End Using

    Return decipherText
End Function
```

Comment: The result of encrypted text are arbitrary bytes.  They can *not* be converted to text, your StreamReader.ReadToEnd() call will randomly crash or destroy the encrypted byte values.   Encoding with Convert.ToBase64String() is the common approach.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the help. I would be glad If you could check the update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cipher text will contain unprintable characters as it will use the whole range from 0 to 255 for each byte. If you want to send the cipher text as a string then I would base64 encode the cipher text first.

change

```
rd = New IO.StreamReader(outFsaux, Text.Encoding.ASCII)
cipherText = rd.ReadToEnd()
```

to

```
cipherText = System.Convert.ToBase64String(outFsaux.ToArray())
```

The code syntax may be a little off as I don't program in VB.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I would be glad If you could check the update

Comment: base64 encoding and decoding is lossless. Everything in the stream when you base64 encoding it, will be in your base64 decoded version. You have wrapped a streamwriter around your stream, which doesn't necessarily write to the underlying stream when you write to the streamwriter. You shouldn't really mix writing to a stream from different things that wrap around the stream. You could try calling flush on your streamwriter straight after writing your key and iv to the streamwriter to ensure that it writes it to the underlying stream immediately.

Comment: DanL, thanks again. I finally got it working, thanks to yours comments. I found 2 more problems. First of all, i found a first problem with the encoding on cipher function, that I could resolve for my own. I could resolve the second problem after flushing the streams. I accepted your answer as the solution :D